# Insert DataGridView values into MySql database. c#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I want to add new values to MySql database from dataGridView1. The code itself appears to be correct, no errors in Visual Studio 2012, but there is no data inserted in my db. 
Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   confirm exec = new confirm();      
}

public class confirm
{
   public void method(DataGridViewCellEventArgs f)
   {
      DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
      Label label1 = new Label(); // contains User ID which is used for payer_code
      Label label6 = new Label(); // contains current dayTime

      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {
         if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[f.RowIndex].Cells["paidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == true)
         {
            try
            {
               string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=contractsdb; Uid=root; Pwd=";
               MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
               MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
               cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
               connection.Open();
               cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO payments(pay_name, pay_code, payer_code, pay_sum, pay_date)VALUES(@pay_name, @pay_code, @payer_code, @pay_sum, @pay_date)";
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay_name", dataGridView1.Rows[f.RowIndex].Cells["contractnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay_code", dataGridView1.Rows[f.RowIndex].Cells["contractcodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payer_code", label1.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay_sum", dataGridView1.Rows[f.RowIndex].Cells["sumDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pay_date", label6.Text);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connection.Close();
            }   

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: May be it is not even going into the `if` check

Comment: Well, it could be, but I'm lost here... Is there any other way for this to work  ?

Comment: Set a `break point` on line `connection.Open()` and check if it gets to there or not. I think it doesn't

Comment: I've put the breakpoint just as you said and when I press the button, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Are you working with an existing DataGridView..? if so why do you have this line `DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();`

Comment: @DJ KRAZE, because I'm using this in a class, I guess.

Comment: @user3041437 It means your datagridview has no rows in it, thats why it never goes into the `if`. Put some data in the gridview and then try to execute the query

Comment: @Shaharyar But I do add the data into gridview before executing this. Here's the code: http://codepaste.net/xzg8xv

Comment: you have no data perhaps you need to do this in stead Are you working with an existing DataGridView..? if so why do you have this line `DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();` also shouldn't this line `if ((bool)dataGridView1.Rows[f.RowIndex].Cells["paidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == true) `be checking against if(row[0]["paidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].ToString() == true.ToString()){}'

Comment: I've no idea why are you doing this `DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();`

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm doing this because the rest of the code is in a class, without this code i get this error: "Cannot access a non-static member of outer type..."

Comment: @DJKRAZE, Tried your IF statement, got an error: "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding something about OOP. Do it like this:

your `confirm` class method should also have the reference of `datagridview1` (you are creating an empty `datagridview` so it never goes even into the `foreach` loop)

```
public void method(DataGridView datagridview1) //remove your first argument, you don't need it anymore
{
    //delete the line "DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();"
    //and keep the rest of the code as it is
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells["paidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].Value == true) //it will check every row, and you don't need "DataGridViewCellEventArgs" argument now
        {
            try
            {
                //your code, it will be same here
            }
        }
}
```

for calling the method:

(use the same button_click event as you were doing)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    confirm exec = new confirm();      
    exec.method(datagridview1); //pass "datagridview1" reference
}
```

It will pass the reference of your original `datagridview1` to the `confirm` class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming :) What should I put instead of "yourfirstargument"?

Comment: It is an event argument. When and where are you calling `method`?

Comment: Um, I thought that the `method` is called automatically when I attach a `public class confirm` `to button2_Click`.

Comment: But "DataGridViewCellEventArgs" will not be available without any event. Check the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I feel so stupid... now I get this error : http://imageshack.com/a/img34/2830/vmhv.jpg

Comment: Don't feel like this bro ! we're here to help you. What do you want to do? can you shortly define me so i will give you a better solution. Precisely define the whole scenario

Comment: The thing is, I need to write data into `datagrid` from DB(mysql), the data would display users personal contratcts, and the `datagrid` should contain a `checkbox` in it, which if checked (by user), means that contract is paid for.  Then, a user of the program clicks the "confirm" button to write data into "payments" database table, which stores **paid** contracts only.

Comment: I've updated my entire answer. Read it carefully now